# Qt tablewidget add row pointer?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program with ~12 tablewidgets, how can I set up a function to add rows to all of the 12 tables in one function?

i.e.

```
main{

    addRow(tablewidget1);
    addRow(tablewidget2);
    // etc
}

addRow(*tablewidget){

    int row = tablewidget->rowCount();

    tablewidget->insertRow(row);

    QTableWidgetItem *item0 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item0->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    tablewidget->setItem(row, 0, item0);

    QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item0->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    tablewidget->setItem(row, 1, item1);
}
```

Comment: If you add the same data to the same views, you could consider using a single QStandardItemModel + QTableViews instead of QTableWidget.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array or a vector with all your widgets in, you could do

```
void main()
{
    std::vector<tablewidgets> widgets;

    // Some initialization code the widgets.

    addMyWidgets(widgets);
}

void addMyWidgets(std::vector<tablewidget>& widgets)
{
    for(std::vector<tablewidget>::iterator it = widgets.begin(), end = widgets.end();
        it != end;
        ++it)
    {
        addRow(*it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to not use a reference pointer..

```
main{

addRow(tablewidget1);
addRow(tablewidget2);
// etc
```

}

addRow(QTableWidget*tablewidget){

```
int row = tablewidget->rowCount();

tablewidget->insertRow(row);

QTableWidgetItem *item0 = new QTableWidgetItem;
item0->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
tablewidget->setItem(row, 0, item0);

QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
item0->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
tablewidget->setItem(row, 1, item1);
```

}